# Pass env var in makefile as optional

Tags: bash, makefile, gnu-make

I have a command in a makefile that executes a bash script:

```
test:
 ./script.sh
```

The script has getopts implemented so it can be called like this:

```
./script.sh -n 10
```

what can in bash be accomplished by:

```
./script.sh ${n:+ -n\ "${n}"}
```

But when I put this construction to makefile it produces empty string.

```
test:
 ./script.sh  ${n:+ -n\ "${n}"}
```

And I can not simply use `./scipt.sh $(n)` as I need the `-n` prefix.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$` has a special meaning in the makefile, since [it is used for `make` variable references](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Rule-Syntax.html).

The `${n:+ -n\ "${n}"}` part in your recipe's command is being expanded by `make` (and not `bash`) which results into an empty string, and that is what `bash` receives:

```
./script.sh
```

---

You can however *escape* a `$` by preceding it with an additional `$`:

```
test:
 ./script.sh  $${n:+ -n\ "$${n}"}
```

This way, `bash` will receive the following command to execute:

```
./script.sh  ${n:+ -n\ "${n}"}
```